# IOS 7 & app crashes when using UIwebview to display webpage that uses google maps api

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, google-maps-api-3, uiwebview

we have a app that supports IOS 7 & 8. we have a web page that loads google map with the different markers.

UIWebView is used to load above page. the page loads fine but, if we zoom in or zoom out too much on the map while in street view the app gets crashed without any crash logs.
a. happens only when in street view.
b. reproducible on safari as well if we use that page directly.

is that a bug on google maps api or if anyone can help fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were able to replicate this crash on Safari App itself, then you're safe to use it.
It looks like a bug that has to do with Google Maps, so you're safe.
You can also report this bug to Google so they can fix it ASAP.